# Border not visible in table

Tags: html, css

[image]border-left is not visible in every first column of each row.

Note: There is restriction with HTML markup, i cant change the page markup or cant add or remove any class. I have to fix it by using existing css classes.

js fiddle: **//jsfiddle.net/w9Z3H/1/**

Problem is in last table grid, i need border all around every column.

Comment: -1 No! Post an example that illustrates your problem and can help others too, I'm not going to wade through a jsfiddle of your entire page while you sit back and wait for me to fix it.

Comment: Praveen you have uploaded a huge CSS file.. which causing us a lot of trouble. Also my jsfiddle can't handled whis huge amount of code and getting crashed every time.

Comment: @all..i have shortened the markup and attached the issue screen shot for ur reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your Code is too wide, its really hard to catch the root cause, However I've found some solution although not perfect but some workaround solution.

This is the CSS you have to add

```
.cvl-list-panel table{border-left:1px solid transparent;}
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w9Z3H/3/)**.